# Can I promote a Trello card to a list?

Tags: trello

What it says on the tin, really. I have a list that I use as my 'big ideas'. Then, when I start on one I want to promote it to a list, perhaps with each activity on the card (notes, checklist etc) promoted to a card in turn.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this right now. We haven't had much call for it either. Card as board has been a more frequent request.

Comment: There might be some who realize that going from card to board is too big of a jump. Board-to-list, card-to-list, and list-to-board would be nice intermediate options for refactoring purposes.